# FFMPEG: Using av_write_frame AFTER av_write_trailer

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using avio_alloc_context with my own "write_buffer_proc" to override file i/o.
I am trying to continue writing the stream with av_write_frame AFTER av_write_trailer was called.
But av_write_trailer has some strange side effects.

The result is AV in module 'avformat-58.dll' (Read of address 0000000000000090)
I think that FormatContext becomes invalid after av_write_trailer.
How Can I fix it?
Can I try to save FormatContext somewhere before calling av_write_trailer ?